# Scikit learn multi-class classification for support vector machines

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, scikits

I want to know whether `LinearSVC` supports multi-class classification by default or do we have to wrap it in  `OneVsRestClassifier` like:

```
 OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
```

Comment: Kindly Edit your Question...

Comment: All classifiers in scikit-learn do: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html

Answer (score 5):

According to [this part of the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm):

> SVC, NuSVC and **LinearSVC** are classes capable of performing multi-class classification on a dataset.
>
> [...]
>
> On the other hand, **LinearSVC** implements “one-vs-the-rest” multi-class strategy, thus training n_class models. If there are only two classes, only one model is trained:

So it supports multiclass classification by default.