# What is the difference between OneVsRestClassifier with SVC and SVC with decision_function_shape='ovr'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I thought it should be the same, but for method `decision_function()` I get different results. And SVC with only `decision_function_shape='ovr'` is really faster.

Related: [Scikit learn multi-class classification for support vector machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338872/scikit-learn-multi-class-classification-for-support-vector-machines)

Comment: I have found these issues on github repo 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10752 and 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5495
which are maybe related, but I still don't really understand and it doesn't provide an explicit answer for OP's question.

Comment: [Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-algorithms) provides some insight for OvO case, where it says that `sklearn.svm.SVC` supports *Multiclass as One-Vs-One* without need of using any meta-estimators (i.e. `OneVsOneClassifier`).

However it is still not clear how should be `SVC` used in combination with `OneVsRestClassifier` when we do want to use meta-estimator and for example do OneVsRest multi-class classification. 

Also it is not clear what role plays `decision_function_shape : ‘ovo’ / ‘ovr’` in all of this.

Answer (score 6):

I got some clarification on the [documentation of LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) in the See also heading, where SVC is mentioned.

> SVC
>
> Implementation of Support Vector Machine classifier using libsvm:
>
> ....
>
> ....
>
> Furthermore SVC multi-class mode is implemented using one vs one scheme while LinearSVC uses one
>   vs the rest. It is possible to implement one vs the rest with SVC by
>   using the sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier wrapper.
>
> ....

Also, SVC delegates all the training to the underlying `libsvm` library, which handles the multi-class case as `'OvO'` (even if the decision_function_shape = 'ovr').

Its mentioned in the issue @delusionX mentioned that `decision_function_shape` is just for compatibility with scikit API. Its most probably, that all other estimators handle the multi-class as OvR and so when SVC is used in combination with other things, (Like for example in a Pipeline, GridSearchCV, Or wrappers like OneVsRestClassifier) returning a OvO decision function breaks the working of others. But I could not find that written explicitly anywhere.

Fun fact: [OneVsOneClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.decision_function) also returns a decision function which confirms with the shape of OvR.

Answer (score 0):

> However, note that internally, one-vs-one (‘ovo’) is always used as a multi-class strategy to train models; an ovr matrix is only constructed from the ovo matrix. The parameter is ignored for binary classification.

From sklearn SVC official document https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html, it seems that the ovr strategy is not really implemented. The ovr results are inferred from the ovo output matrixes.

So I guess if you want to follow ovr strategy strictly, OneVsRestClassifier is a better choice.