# Which decision_function_shape for sklearn.svm.SVC when using OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I am doing multi-label classification where I am trying to predict correct tags to questions:

(X = questions, y = list of tags for each question from X).

I am wondering, which `decision_function_shape` for [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) should be be used with [`OneVsRestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html)?

From docs we can read that `decision_function_shape` can have two values `'ovo'` and `'ovr'`:

> **decision_function_shape** : ‘ovo’, ‘ovr’ or None, default=None
>
> Whether to return a one-vs-rest (‘ovr’) decision function of shape (n_samples, n_classes) as all other classifiers, or the original
>   one-vs-one (‘ovo’) decision function of libsvm which has shape
>   (n_samples, n_classes * (n_classes - 1) / 2). The default of None will
>   currently behave as ‘ovo’ for backward compatibility and raise a
>   deprecation warning, but will change ‘ovr’ in 0.19.

But I still don't understand what is the difference between:

```
# First decision_function_shape set to 'ovo'
estim = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', decision_function_shape ='ovo'))

# Second decision_function_shape set to 'ovr'
estim = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', decision_function_shape ='ovr'))
```

Which `decision_function_shape` should be used for [multi-label classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-algorithms) problem?

**EDIT:** [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604468/what-is-the-difference-between-onevsrestclassifier-with-svc-and-svc-with-decisio?rq=1) asking a similar thing with no answer.

Comment: You could try both and check which one gives better results for your specific data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question of which should be used is best left up to a situational. That could easily be a part of your GridSearch. But just intuitively I would feel that as far as differences go you are going to be doing the same thing. Here is my reasoning:

`OneVsRestClassifier` is designed to model each class against all of the other classes independently, and create a classifier for each situation. The way I understand this process is that `OneVsRestClassifier` grabs a class, and creates a binary label for whether a point is or isn't that class. Then this labelling gets fed into whatever estimator you have chosen to use. I believe the confusion comes in in that `SVC` also allows you to make this same choice, but in effect with this implementation the choice will not matter because you will always only be feeding two classes into the `SVC`.

And here is an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = load_iris()

X, y = data.data, data.target
estim1 = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', decision_function_shape='ovo'))
estim1.fit(X,y)

estim2 = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', decision_function_shape='ovr'))
estim2.fit(X,y)

print(estim1.coef_ == estim2.coef_)
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So you can see the coefficients are all equal for all three estimators built by the two models. Granted this dataset only has 150 samples and 3 classes so it is possible these results could be different for a more complex dataset, but it's a simple proof of concept.

Comment: To add here,SVC will internally always use the `OvO`, the decision_function_shape is for compatibility only, its not used in fitting of data. So the `coef_` will always be equal. I have answered this in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604468/what-is-the-difference-between-onevsrestclassifier-with-svc-and-svc-with-decisio?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

The shape of the decision functions are different because `ovo` trains a classifier for each **2-pair class combination** whereas `ovr` trains one classifier for each class fitted against all other classes.

The best example I could find can be [found here on http://scikit-learn.org](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#multi-class-classification):

> **SVC** and **NuSVC** implement the “one-against-one” approach (Knerr et al.,
>   1990) for multi- class classification. If `n_class` is the number of
>   classes, then `n_class * (n_class - 1) / 2` classifiers are constructed
>   and each one trains data from two classes. To provide a consistent
>   interface with other classifiers, the `decision_function_shape` option
>   allows to aggregate the results of the “one-against-one” classifiers
>   to a decision function of shape (n_samples, n_classes)

```
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')
>>> clf.fit(X, Y) 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovo', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
>>> dec.shape[1] # 4 classes: 4*3/2 = 6
6
>>> clf.decision_function_shape = "ovr"
>>> dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
>>> dec.shape[1] # 4 classes
4
```

**What does this mean in simple terms?**

To understand what `n_class * (n_class - 1) / 2` means, generate two-class combinations using `itertools.combinations`.

```
def ovo_classifiers(classes):
    import itertools
    n_class = len(classes)
    n = n_class * (n_class - 1) / 2
    combos = itertools.combinations(classes, 2)
    return (n, list(combos))

>>> ovo_classifiers(['a', 'b', 'c'])
(3.0, [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')])
>>> ovo_classifiers(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
(6.0, [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')])
```

**Which estimator should be used for multi-label classification?**

In your situation, you have a question with multiple tags (like here on StackOverflow). If you know your tags (classes) in-advance, I might suggest `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())` but you could try DecisionTreeClassifier or RandomForestClassifier (I think):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier, OneVsOneClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Tags': [['python', 'pandas'], ['c#', '.net'], ['ruby'],
           ['python'], ['c#'], ['sklearn', 'python']],
  'Questions': ['This is a post about python and pandas is great.',
           'This is a c# post and i hate .net',
           'What is ruby on rails?', 'who else loves python',
           'where to learn c#', 'sklearn is a python package for machine learning']},
                  columns=['Questions', 'Tags'])

X = df['Questions']
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = mlb.fit_transform(df['Tags'].values)

pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('vect', CountVectorizer(token_pattern='|'.join(mlb.classes_))),
  ('linear_svc', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))
  ])
pipeline.fit(X, y)

final = pd.DataFrame(pipeline.predict(X), index=X, columns=mlb.classes_)

def predict(text):
  return pd.DataFrame(pipeline.predict(text), index=text, columns=mlb.classes_)

test = ['is python better than c#', 'should i learn c#',
        'should i learn sklearn or tensorflow',
        'ruby or c# i am a dinosaur',
        'is .net still relevant']
print(predict(test))
```

Output:

```
                                      .net  c#  pandas  python  ruby  sklearn
is python better than c#                 0   1       0       1     0        0
should i learn c#                        0   1       0       0     0        0
should i learn sklearn or tensorflow     0   0       0       0     0        1
ruby or c# i am a dinosaur               0   1       0       0     1        0
is .net still relevant                   1   0       0       0     0        0
```

Comment: Great answer. Could you please explain why would you use LinearSVC() instead of SVC(kernel='linear') for this particular problem? Aren't they basically the same just with some implementation differences according to docs? (I know about only one advantage of LinearSVC() - it scales better for bigger datasets)